# Reemplazo de palabras en archivo de texto: no se realizan los cambios

Tags: c++

En un archivo de problemas de exámenes viejos de C++ me topé con este en particular:

> En un archivo de texto llamado PROSA.TXT se almacena un texto con una
> introducción a la tecnología informática. Se desea mediante un programa C++, reemplazar en el
> archivo la palabra “software” por “programa”. Considere que “software” puede aparecer en una línea
> más de una vez. Informe la cantidad de palabras reemplazadas. El archivo PROSA.TXT debe quedar
> modificado con los reemplazos.

Planteé la solución al problema de esta manera:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    fstream archi("PROSA.txt");
    string todoeltexto = "", linea;
    while(getline(archi,linea)){
        todoeltexto += linea + " ";
    }
    
    int conteo = 0;
    string viejo = "software";
    string nuevo = "programa";
    size_t pos = todoeltexto.find(viejo);
    while(pos != string::npos) {
        todoeltexto.replace(pos, viejo.length(), nuevo);
        pos = todoeltexto.find(viejo,pos+viejo.length());
        conteo++;
    }
    

    archi << todoeltexto;
    cout << conteo;
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Pero no realiza ningún cambio en el texto asociado. El contador indica cuántas veces encontró "software", al menos. Adjunto el archivo txt en cuestión:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
> Ut enim ad minim software, quis nostrud software ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla software.
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non software, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Podrían decirme dónde está mi error? Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás intentando guardar tu string modificada en el mismo archivo PROSA.txt del que lees.
En este caso el fichero se abre en modo lectura al hacer la primera petición de una línea y una vez leemos todas las líneas llegamos al EOF. De modo que no podemos escribir la información ya que hemos llegado al fin del fichero.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  fstream archi("PROSA.txt");
  string todoeltexto = "", linea;
  while(getline(archi,linea)){
      todoeltexto += linea + "\n";
  }

  int conteo = 0;
  string viejo = "software";
  string nuevo = "programa";
  size_t pos = todoeltexto.find(viejo);
  while(pos != string::npos) {
    todoeltexto.replace(pos, viejo.length(), nuevo);
    pos = todoeltexto.find(viejo,pos+viejo.length());
    conteo++;
  }

archi.close();
archi.open("PROSA.txt");
archi << todoeltexto;
cout << conteo;



  return 0;
}
```

Para poder escribir en el archivo basta con cerrarlo y volver a abrirlo.
Además en el bucle donde concatenas las líneas del fichero en vez de añadir un espacio final debes añadir un salto de línea. Así la única modificación final será "software" por "programa"

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Me recomendarías entonces usar ifstream y ofstream por separado (para escribir y leer respectivamente)? Para qué casos recomendarías utilizar fstream?

Comment: Yo utilizaría ofstream e ifstream cuando las operaciones sobre el fichero sean de un solo tipo.  El motivo es que si por ejemplo queremos leer "PROSA.txt", y después escribir en él, hay que asegurarse de leer el fichero entero antes de utilizar `ofstream archi("PROSA.txt")`  de lo contrario se elimina el contenido del fichero (si no indicamos modo append) y perderíamos la información.  fstream para un caso de escritura y lectura me parece más apropiado, teniendo sólo que cerrar el archivo una vez leído y abrirlo de nuevo para escribir.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas usando el `fstream` de una manera incorrecta. Estas escribiendo solo asi al archivo, y eso no funciona asi. Toma el siguiente codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void) {
    std::fstream archivo("ejemplo.txt");
    std::string texto;
    archivo >> texto;

    std::cout << "Read: " << texto << '\n';

    for (char& c : texto) {
        c = static_cast<char>(std::toupper(c));
    }

    //archivo.seekg(0, std::fstream::beg);
    std::cout << "Wrote: " << texto << '\n';
    archivo << texto << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Mi archivo ejemplo.txt era solo asi:

```
hola
```

Pruebalo primero solo asi, y despues quitale el comentario a la linea `//archivo.seekg(0, std::fstream::beg);`. Vas a ver la diferencia. Lo que hacemos es regresar al principio para sobreescribir lo que ya habia. Aunque yo la verdad prefiero cerrar y reabrir el archivo, usando `ofstream` y `ifstream`, ya que asi el encuentro menos problemas.